# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus' on Python 3.8.2 32-bit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbus, notify

I tried using `notify2` in a program but running the code outputted `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus'`.

I have tried installing `dbus` through `pip install dbus-python` but it also outputted only error `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Installing was the way to go. But you have only told us that the install failed. Without the output from `pip` we can't tell you any more than that either.

Comment: If you are using Python3, then try installing `dbus` with `sudo apt install python3-dbus`